# What are main reasons for not connecting?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I can't connect to many of my friends yet they can connect to me. What are the main reasons for people not being able to connect? Is it something to do with my Firewall? My Internet Firewall is low and I'm pretty sure my PC Firewall accepts the program.

Comment: Are you behind a router?  Have you port forwarded the ports needed?

Comment: What do you mean behind? And no there is no ports I need to port forward.

Comment: Do you use a router?  Or is your laptop/computer plugged directly into the internet box you have?  In some cases, your internet box is also a router.  Does it have more than one ethernet port on it?

Comment: My PC is connected to the router by a lan cable.

Comment: So, yes, you're behind a router, then.  Which means you probably need to do some port forwarding in order for this game to get routed to your computer properly.

Comment: But I am using "Log me in Hamachi" so that should cause me not to have to port forward right?

Comment: Using Hamachi is a pretty important detail. You should put that in your question, since it is definitely part of how your connection is(n't) working.

Comment: I'm not sure how Hamachi works, but I suspect that's at the heart of the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that you can connect to them but they cannot connect to you when using Hamachi, since by definition you can reach each other via LAN.

I would like to help but this sounds like a case of Paradox being incapable of writing decent Netcode. Every paradox game has had bad Netcode and been unstable, had connection issues, etc. They claim to have spent a lot of focus on the EU4 netcode and its still not reliable.

Basically, I suggest you just connect to your friend, since the problem may well not be on your end. The mysteries behind paradox multiplayer don't tend to get solved.